# Create a new composable element every second

Tags: while-loop, kotlin-coroutines, delay

I'm trying to have a loop that shoots a ball every second.
The ball itself has a coroutine that animate its offsetX.
Below I have a Row with a Button that activates a coroutine with a while loop that shoots Balls. The way I did it doesn't obviously work: one ball is shot and that's it.
How can I trigger a loop that keeps shooting balls and doesn't interfere with the coroutine within the ball itself?
Being new to compose, I can't still figure out how to do it. Can someone help?

This is the Row with the Button, the coroutinge, the infinite while loop and the Ball created when isLoading changes.

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(noteSize * scoreLength)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            Button(
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Red),
                onClick = {                    
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                       while (true){
                         isLoading = true
                         delay(1000)
                         isLoading = false
                       }                       
                    }
                }) { 
                Text(text = "shoot")
            }

            if (isLoading) Ball(noteSize, noteSize / 2 + (noteSize / 2) * 8, 8, w)               
          }
}
```

And this is the Note that when it gets shot moves to the left. The Note as a composable is actually an OutlinedButton.

```
@Composable
fun Ball(
    noteSize: Dp,
    verticalOffSet: Dp,
    target: Float,
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val offsetX = remember { Animatable(350f) }
    val v = verticalOffSet.dpToPx().toInt()

    OutlinedButton(
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Red),
        onClick = { },
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    offsetX.value.toInt(),
                    v
                )
            }
            .size(noteSize),
        shape = CircleShape
    ) { }
    coroutineScope.launch {
        offsetX.animateTo(
            targetValue = -target,
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 3000, easing = LinearEasing))
    }
}
```

Comment: That `if (isLoading)` statement doesn't create new balls. It shows or hides that ball. Add another `delay(1000)` after `isLoading = false` and you'll clearly see it.

Comment: OMG! it was so easy! thanks!! now, since this works, the second part of my question "...doesn't interfere with the coroutine within the ball itself", which means: once shot, the ball should keep running for 3 seconds, as you can see in the ball's animationSpec, but it goes on only for 1 second until it's triggered again. How can I make the ball's coroutine independent of the button's coroutine?

Comment: It is independent, but you're a little confused. All the corotuine does is show and hide the ball. When the ball is hidden, it is taken out of the UI tree, so when it is "shown again", it's actually a brand new ball, not the same one. You need to store every ball info in a list and create a ball for every item in the list.

Comment: I'm very confused, indeed. At least since I moved from my comfortable Java/XML to Kotlin/Compose. I arrived today at the same conclusion as yours, but didn't have the time to implemented. At least I wasn't so off. Thank you!